# ABL Substring 1 character to 2 characters

Tags: substring, openedge, progress-4gl

fairly new to ABL here. I have a question where I just cannot figure out the answer.

I have job numbers in sequence such 99999-0, 99999-2, 99999-3 and could go well into 99999-150. However, I need to interpret jobs 99999-0 through 99999-9 as 99999-00 through 99999-09 where I am writing these interpreted values to a UD field. I'm sure it is simple but being a newb, I cannot figure it out.

Thank you in advance.

Chris

Comment: I think I figured it out. How does this look?
if JobAsmbl.AssemblySeq < 10 then Substring(JobHead.JobNum, 1, 5) + "-" +  '0' + String(JobAsmbl.AssemblySeq) else
Substring(JobHead.JobNum, 1, 5) + "-" +  String(JobAsmbl.AssemblySeq, '00')

Comment: That doesn't look like it has much to do with the sample job numbers shown in your question.

Comment: Are you asking how to format the number with leading digits? Or how to select numbers matching a value?  If you're building logic based on substrings of this ID, consider breaking the value into fields in your schema so you can access them more readily.

Comment: Good point - if you have control over this schema you should break the job numbers into 2 fields.  Composite fields are a horrible hack. It's one thing to work with them if someone else forced it on you but if you have control you  would be much better off breaking it up.

Answer (score 2):

This is a little  light on error checking etc and I haven't actually syntax checked it but:

```
function X returns character ( jobNum as character ):
  return( string( integer( entry( 2, jobNum, "-" )), "99" ).
end.
```

Comment: I came here to write something very similar to this. +1 for this approach.

Comment: If it's a number and you know it, why return a string?

Comment: Personally, my confidence that it will always be a number is low.